# Creating multiple tables/colums with one query

Tags: mysql

my task is to make tables/columns, but im not sure how would i approach to it doing with one query only? 
Tables/colums can be found there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gUPm.jpg

I tried to manually create database via phpmyadmin (using xampp) and entered manually the tables, but that takes way too much time, can anybody direct me?

Comment: You can export database into SQL file and get all tables creation commands from them. See: https://superuser.com/questions/168595/how-to-export-mysql-schema-from-phpmyadmin

Comment: I'm not trying to export the SQL file because i'm not migrating from another site.

Comment: You cannot modify multiple table by single query. But you can prepare series of query to do it.